# Passing Multiple values via Ajax to a MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is the Ajax Call:

```
        var selectedProductOptions = new Array();

    $(".optionSelectionBox").each(function () {
        selectedProductOptions.push($(this).val());
    });

$.ajax({
        url: "/Cart/AddItem",
        type: 'post',

        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            productId : @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Product.Id),
            selectedOptions : selectedProductOptions,
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                alert("test Hello Success");
            }

            alert("test HELLO Fail");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + "- Error");
        }
    });
```

And this is controller that is reciveing the call.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddItem(string productId, List<string> selectedOptions)
    {
     //Code here        
    }
```

When I set a break point on the action it gets hit which is what I want but..... productId and selectedOptions are both NULL.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: What data is stored in `selectedProductOptions`? Can you give an example?

Comment: selectedProductOptions: Array[4]
0: "4"
1: "1"
2: "7"
3: "10"   << Thats the object from the chrome developer tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK its working Now.... :-)

And this is my solution, hopefully it will help others.

This is the controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddItem(string formData)
    {

    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    AddItemModel addItemModel  = js.Deserialize<AddItemModel>(formData);


   //Other Code here

        return new JsonResult();
    }

    public class AddItemModel
    {
        public List<string> selectedOptions { get; set; }
        public string productId { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Cart/AddItem",
        type: 'post',

        data: "formData=" + JSON.stringify(cartItem),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                alert("test Hello Success");
            }

            alert("test HELLO Fail");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + "- Error");
        }
    });
```

There seems to be a lot of different ways in doing this, I got this working this time, but I still don't know why the the first way didn't work, would love for some who really understands this to explain why it didn't work, and what is going on under the hood.

Thanks Guys... on to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `,` in `selectedOptions : selectedProductOptions,`

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 
        productId : @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Product.Id),
        selectedOptions : selectedProductOptions
    }),
```

**Edit**

Try with this too

```
 data: {
 productId: @Html.ValueFor(m = > m.Product.Id),
 selectedOptions: JSON.stringify(selectedProductOptions)
 },
```

Comment: Just tried that...Still no Joy... both productId and selectedOptions are still null

Comment: I have also tried to change selectedOptions to a List<int> to see if that helps.. No Joy

Answer (score 1):

You can also make something like this:

create new class:

```
public class AddItemModel
    {
        public List<string> selectedOptions { get; set; }
        public string productId { get; set; }
    }
```

and modify your code:

```
public JsonResult AddItem(AddItemModel aim)
```

and ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                    aim: {
                        productId : @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Product.Id),
                        selectedOptions : selectedProductOptions                           
                    }
```

this also should work

Comment: Tried that as well.. hits the break point but the object aim is set, but the selectedProductOptions and productId is still null... *sigh* Im thinking JS serializer is needed here....